# The object of the preposition "of"

Tags: meaning, prepositions

For example, a skyscraper in a large city is a significantly more complex object than a modest family dwelling in a small town, but the underlying principles of construction and design, **including questions of mechanics, energy and information distribution, the sizes of electrical outlets, water faucets, telephones, laptops, doors, etc.**, all remain approximately the same independent of the size of the building.

1.
In the above sentence, is it

1. including questions of (mechanics, energy and information distribution, the sizes of ~~~)

or

2. including (questions of mechanics), (energy and information distribution), (the sizes of ~)

??

2. Also, is it

1. (the sizes of electrical outlets), (water faucets), (telephones), (laptops), (doors) ~

or

2. the sizes of (electrical outlets, water faucets, telephones, laptops, doors)

??

Which one is right? And why?

Comment: (1) in the first case and (2) in the second (and why did you list them in reverse order? It makes answering more difficult), because it's the simplest interpretation in both cases. Clearness is not so much about being unambiguous (you can't avoid ambiguity, especially in writing) as it is about leading the reader to the understanding you want them to get. Lead the way down the main trail and don't worry about making sure there aren't any others for them to follow.

Comment: I think the writer is guilty of some woolly thinking - why on earth would he mention *[the underlying principles of construction and design OR the size of] **laptops*** when comparing & contrasting *skyscraper + modest family dwelling*? It's poor quality text, however you parse it.